# javascript sort key value pair on frequency in different array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I would like to store product information in a key, value array, with the key being the unique product url. Then I would also like to store the visit frequency of each of these products. I will store these objects as window.localStorage items, but that's not very important.

The thing I had in mind was two key value arrays:

```
//product information
prods["url"] = ["name:product_x,type:category_x,price:50"]
//product visits frequency
freq["url"] = [6]
```

Then I would like to sort these prods based on the frequency.

Is that possible?

Hope you guys can help! Thanks a lot

Comment: please add some raw data.

Comment: What is the benefit of multiple key-value arrays here? Why not a single key-value array that maps `url` to a JavaScript *object*. Then on the object you can put whatever you want (like a property for `name`, a property for `type`, property for `visit_frequency` etc)

Comment: I would consider changing the name of this question to exclude a mention to frequency as a frequency sort is something else entirely and would explain why you never got any answers.

Answer (score 1):

Well you seem to have made several strange choices for your data format/structure. But assuming the format of the "prod" is beyond your control but you can choose your data structure, here's one way to do it.

Rather than two objects both using `url` as a key and having one value field each I've made a single object still keyed on `url` but with the product and frequency information from each in a field.

Objects don't have any inherent order so rather than sorting the table object I sort the keys, your "url"s ordered by ascending frequency.

To show that it's sorted that way I print it out (not in the same format).

For descending frequency, change `data[a].freq - data[b].freq` to `data[b].freq - data[a].freq`

```js
var data = {
  "url": {
    prod: "name:product_x,type:category_x,price:50",
    freq: 6
  },
  "url2": {
    prod: "name:product_y,type:category_y,price:25",
    freq: 3
  }
};

var sorted = Object.keys(data).sort((a, b) => data[a].freq - data[b].freq);

console.log(sorted.map(k => [data[k].freq, k, data[k].prod]));
```

There's more than one way to format the data, which would change the shape of the code here.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:

```
var prods = [
    {url:1, val:[{name:'a',type:'x',price:60}]}, 
    {url:2, val:[{name:'b',type:'x',price:30}]},
    {url:3, val:[{name:'c',type:'x',price:50}]},
    {url:4, val:[{name:'c',type:'x',price:20}]},
    {url:5, val:[{name:'c',type:'x',price:10}]},
    {url:6, val:[{name:'c',type:'x',price:40}]}
];

var freq = [
    {url:1, freq:6},
    {url:2, freq:3},
    {url:3, freq:5},
    {url:4, freq:2},
    {url:5, freq:1},
    {url:6, freq:4}
];

prods.sort(function (a, b) {
  var aU = freq.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.url === a.url;
  });

  var bU = freq.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.url === b.url;
  });

  if (aU[0].freq > bU[0].freq) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (aU[0].freq < bU[0].freq) {
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
});
```